# Backbone view in sails .ejs file

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, view, sails.js

I am trying to access backbone views in sails framework.  I fetch data from the server and I am trying to push them to the DOM. Actually, I ve created a model-controller for the tags I store data from mongo to tags model and I return to backbone the url of tags view. I want to display those data to my DOM element.  I am trying to find how is it possible to do so in the sails since I am receiving is not defined error. My DOM element code is the following:

```
          51| <div id="profiles" class = 'hashTagsCloud'>
          52| <script id="profileTemplate" type="text/template">
       >> 53| <%= tagsCloud.tags.join("&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp")%>
          54| </script>
          55| </div>


      tagsCloud is not defined
```

Where tagsCloud is a item of the json file I got from the server. Backbone code for views:

```
  var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#profiles",
        template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
        render: function(eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
        //push data to obj for map script
        obj = profile.toJSON();
        // Add data to DOM element
        $(this.el).html(profileTemplate);
        }, this);

            return this;


        }


    });
```

The above backbone logic works like a charm in apache. However in sails I got not defined error. How can I define, in proper way, a view for tagsCloud item in my index file?? 
My json file is the following:

```
  [
    {
     tstamp: 1366626103000,
     tagsCloud: {
     sort: "asc",
     tags: [
           "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"
           ]
     },
     id: "529da369380eb213e804a673"
    }
  ]
```

Moreover I add some actions in my homeController file so as to send to ejs file the json data:

```
index: function (req,res)
{

    console.log(req.tags);  // tags is the name of the model-controller
    res.view({
        tags: req.tags
    });
},

'home': function (req,res)
{
    res.view();
}
```

Is there anything I ve to change in backbone view code to properly update my index view???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way to send fetched data to the DOM from the backbone. I ve changed template  code inside backbone code, so as to send directly the data to the DOM element. Here is my code:

```
     _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };

    var TagsView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: "#profiles",
        template: _.template("<div><p>{{ tg.tagsCloud.tags }}</p></div>"),
        render: function(eventName) {

        _.each(this.model.models, function(tags){
        var tagsTemplate = this.template(tags.toJSON());
        //push data to obj for map script
        tg = tags.toJSON();

        // Add data to DOM element
        $(this.el).html(tagsTemplate);
        }, this);
            return this;                   
        }       
        });
```