# Sails and helpers ejs problems.

Tags: backbone.js, sails.js

I am working in a project with sails and ejs, I am trying know in which page I am, I mean if I am in the home site, login, register, .... from the template.

When I try to use,  is_current_page I got always the error "is not defined" I already try to add express-helpers as I have read in this iss [How to configure Sails.js to use EJS view helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354896/backbone-view-in-sails-ejs-file) but without successful.

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get Express-Helpers to work with the beta version of Sails either (v10-rc5 at this time).  I solved this problem by looking at the path, but I won't claim this is the 'right' solution.

```
 if(res.locals.view.path.split('/')[0] === 'view_name'){ ... }
```

If there is another way to determine the current view I would be interested as well.